# IP Log showing something weird

Tags: php, ip, code-injection

Does anybody know what the additional characters on this? I did a whois on the IP at the beginning, it seems to be an Apple owned IP. I googled this, and came up with a sole reddit, and one stack overflow result. Neither of which answered my question.

Also- i googled the subtraction and a bunch of eCommerce sites come up with that string in the search. My thoughts are this is looking for a PHP vulnerability or something.

```
[2019-04-08 03:11:04] - Page Load - IP '17.240.170.56[CHR(0)]"{${print(238947899389478923-34567343546345)}}"'
```

```php
$tz = 'America/Toronto';
date_default_timezone_set($tz);
$myfile = fopen("email.log", "a");
$txt = "[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "] - Page Load - IP '" . get_client_ip() . "'\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to create a good post.

Comment: Show me your logging function that it was printed from.

Comment: And as far as im aware its a common query looking for XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: @TimHinz I've added it to my question

Comment: I'll assume that you're using this function for get_client_ip: https://gist.github.com/vostok1961/31bf1b462ffcd0b2331b58466d452e78 and if that's the case they're able to do it by abusing the forwarded server var and inject their own code into it.

Comment: "note that this function can also lead you very wrong. in particular, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be anything a client chooses to set, whereas REMOTE_ADDR is considerably harder to fake, if client wants to get the actual response. "

Comment: Yep, thats what we're using. So, is this a security issue? Should i just use REMOTE_ADDR rather then this function? @TimHinz

Comment: I don't foresee it being a security issue for a few reasons. 1.) you're writing to a txt file which should never be able to execuse phpcode in any way shape or form. 2.) the fact that you see the PHP code means they didn't find a XSS issue in your site. That said though you should go over your site with a fine tooth comb. Don't leave any open $_GET variables or $_SERVER variables that could drop PHP code that can be executed, watch for sanitizing file uploads, and make sure you're sanitizing all strings. If you're worried about the txt file just do a strip tags on it! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Tim, Still odd how it shows Apple owns the IP on a whois of it. Regardless, Thanks!